# Can the Yii2 assets pipeline watch subdirectories?

Tags: php, yii2

I try to follow the [SASS guidelines](http://sass-guidelin.es/) for my style sheets.  The guidelines suggest putting all code in files topically sorted into 7 folder (6 in our case, due to how Yii handles dependencies).

The Yii2 assets pipeline seems to watch only the `$sourcePath` for changes, ignoring the subdirectories.  Changing a file in the subdirectories doesn't trigger a recompilation.  I had to force recompilation via `$config['components']['assetManager']['forceCopy'] = true;` to ensure that everything is compiled on a page reload after.  This recompiles all the assets and takes about 3 times as long as just recompiling the `scss` files.  Working on a potato became really annoying.

Is there a simple way to let the Yii asset pipeline know about the subdirectories so I can do away with full recompilation every time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a matter of fact you can, but it requires a bit of effort.

In your `AsssetBundle::init()`-function, see if any of the subfolders has a modification time that is more recent than the one from the normal folder, only then set the forceCopy to true.

```
public function init()
{
   parent::init();
   $modified = filemtime($this->sourcePath)
   foreach(['my', 'list', 'of', 'subfolders'] as $folder) {
      $subfolderModified = filemtime($this->sourcePath . '/' . $folder);
      if ($subfolderModified > $modified) {
         $this->publishOptions['forceCopy'] = true;
         break;
      }
   }
}
```

Note that this is largely dummy code, but it serves just to show you the gist of my idea.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I totally didn't know about `publishOptions`.  This doesn't seem completely correct, though.  The above code causes recompilation regardless if there were recent changes.  I went with the following, which has pretty much the same effect:  `public $publishOptions = [
        'forceCopy' => YII_ENV === 'dev',
    ];`

Comment: If you implement and test it, it shouldn't. As I said: this is only a gist of code and not tested. Given what you used as final solution (always recompile on the development environment) it seems that you were looking for something different than what you asked in your question (only compile on development environment).

Comment: The modification time of `$this->sourcePath` is just not a good indicator of when the files were compiled the last time.  I thought I could make it work by using the resulting CSS file, but it's only in the published dir and not easily accessible.  I'll have to find a different way.

Comment: Because the fact that the hash is generated based on the source path & its last modified time, this would mean that (if your assetbundle is being published) it is always into a new and fresh directory (unless the forceCopy is enabled). Under normal circumstances you don't have a compiled version.

Comment: To be honest, on my servers I just use `'forceCopy' => YII_DEBUG;` for development and for staging/production I clear my assets folder during a deploy. That way all assets are re-published right after the deploy and guaranteed to be up to date. Seems like a lot less effort, assuming you have a deployment procedure in place.

Comment: I would do that too, but one of my dev machines is just *sooo slow*.  It works well now with the `touch` of mtime updates.  Thanks again for your help! :)